# Can i share my PC game with my sister?

Tags: steam

I have a sister. There is one computer in our house. All my family members use this computer.   If my sister and I want to play any game, do I have to buy 2 game disks? Or 1 is enough? I am asking is it legal to buy 1 disk install it in Pc? And let others play? Some times relatives visit our house from time to time. Twice (give or take) is it legal to let them play the game in my PC?

Comment: We can't answer questions about legalities, I'm afraid.  We're not lawyers.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you a bit; http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking about legality, which we can't help with.

Comment: This information varies from game to game. Some games don't legally allow anyone but the owner to play, some allow it to be played by anyone.

Answer (score 8):

If you're talking about digital games in your Steam library, **yes**. In fact, Steam even has a service allowing you to do this called [Steam Family Sharing](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing).

If all your family members have a Steam account, it's possible to share your Steam library with those accounts.

> ### Share your computer? Now share your games too.
>
> Steam Family Library Sharing allows family members and their guests to
>   play one another's games while earning their own Steam achievements
>   and saving their own game progress to the Steam Cloud. It's all
>   enabled by authorizing shared computers and users.
>
> ### Want to play this game?
>
> See a family member's installed game that you want to play? Send them
>   a request to authorize you. Once authorized, their library of Steam
>   games becomes available for you to access, download and play.